# Laravel 4: how get failing INSERT query SQL with insert

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-4

I need to work on a legacy product with Laravel 4 (and I cannot update it).

I need to read the real query executed but I cannot get it.

This is my model:

```php
class MigrationData {
    
    protected $log = "";
    
    public function executeMigration($id, $own, $company_id = null)
    {
        DB::transaction(function($conn) use($id, $own, $company_id) {
            DB::connection('connection_01')->transaction(function($conn) use($id, $own, $company_id) {
            // stuffes
            $customer = new Customer();
            try {
                 $customer->save();
                 Log::debug(DB::connection('connection_01')->getQueryLog());
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                 Log::debug(DB::connection('connection_01')->getQueryLog());
            }
            exit();
        })->enableQueryLog();
    })
}
```

I can log other queries, but not the insert (the `INSERT` itself returns an error of Oracle Database but I would track exact query).

Thank you

Comment: Hi @sineverba,did you visit link https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#query-logging `$queries = DB::getQueryLog();`

Comment: Just done. See my code.

Comment: you are using a **very** old version of `Laravel` which **no longer** receives updates, bug fixes nor security patches. It is strongly recommended that you upgrade to the most recent version of `Laravel` which is, at the time of writing this comment, [`Laravel 9`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#laravel-9).

Comment: ths I know. But My preamble is: It's a legacy product and i cannot update it. But thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

The [transaction](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e4e0020a7620f945760a8e47d3d3006482f4eac9/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L449) method doesn't return an instance of its class. Let me give an example:

```php
$response = DB::transaction(function(){

    // ... (Some DB operations)

    return 'Hello World';
});

// It prints "Hello World."
echo $response;
```

Therefore, you cannot make method chaining. Try to separate it like below:

```php
DB::enableQueryLog()

DB::transaction(...);
```